# Multiple modal popup elements, can't set z-index

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, modal-popup

I have two modals that can be opened on the page.
But they both have the same z-index, so I try to set a higher z-index for one of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal','mage/validation'],function($){
        myModal.modal({
            responsive: true,
            zIndex: 950,
            ...
```

But the `zIndex: 950,` doesn't work at all. I wonder maybe it is some deprecated or undocumented option because the off. docs don't mention it.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Update:
I have found out that here

```
baseIndex = zIndex + this._getVisibleCount();
```

`_getVisibleCount()` returns 0 even though one modal is already open. That's my problem.

Comment: You can set z-index for a modal when it gets active state. please visit : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276256/magento-2-2-uncaught-typeerror-this-modal-zindex-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no `zIndex/z-index` property available for modals. It will set higher `z-index` on the last created popup. So last created popup will be always on top with higher `z-index`.

But you can use `modalClass` property to set CSS class and set required `z-index` on that class.

```
var options = {
  ...
  modalClass: 'css_class_for_z_index'
  ...
};
```

**OR** if you want to set `z-index` dynamically, you can overwrite `_setActive` function in modal.js. Check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276256/magento-2-2-uncaught-typeerror-this-modal-zindex-is-not-a-function) for more.